# Custom shipping method admin form issues

Tags: orocommerce

I've created a custom shipping integration ([based on this guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/extend-commerce/shipping)) that calculates the shipping price based on a percentage of the subtotal. This percentage is set in the shipping method settings.

Everything works fine on the frontend part, the shipping price is calculated correctly.

The problems I have lies in the admin backoffice, in the shipping method settings page. The first problem that I have is that the text box to set the percentage is preceded by the currency, which will confuse the user as it is expecting not a flat rate price, but a percentage of the order's subtotal.

I have the same problem on the list of added shipping methods, the value I set is preceded by the currency, and this is not good.

There is a "add a template" section in the guide which I followed, but the template doesn't seem to affect anything. I tried putting bogus letters in the template and clearing the cache, but they did not appear anywhere on the settings page.

What I would like to do here is either remove the currency indicator completely, or to replace it with a %.

The second problem I have is that the language isn't taken into account. I have created a messages.en.yml file and a messages.fr.yml file. Both follow the same structure of course, and all strings are translated. But if I set OroCommerce in French, I don't get my translated strings, but the english ones.

Here's a screenshot that shows both my problems :

[image]

(Strings like "Price percentage" should be translated)

Do you have an idea on how I could fix these issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Andrey's answer, I managed to have something that works. I'll add a few more details for anyone that had the same issue.

For the issue with the translation, it seems that renaming the file by adding the locale `messages.fr_FR.yml` fixed the issue.

Concerning the currency part on the admin menu, you have to create a `jsmodules.yml` file in the `Resources/config` folder of your bundle, **NOT** `Resources/config/oro`, which is why none of my configs were taken into account.

When writing your jsmodules file, when using `map`, if you're overriding a JS file, you **have to** omit the file extension. When you're overriding something else, say an HTML file, you **have** to put the file extension.

This is how my file is written :

```yaml
map:
  "*":
    oroshipping/js/app/views/shipping-rule-method-view: gdmshipping/js/shipping-rule-method-view
```

There is one caveat, though. This will replace the display for all shipping integrations, so the currency symbol will be replaced/removed for all other shipping types, such as Flat Rate, so keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Currency is added in [shipping-rule-method-view.js](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/4.2.0/src/Oro/Bundle/ShippingBundle/Resources/public/js/app/views/shipping-rule-method-view.js#L223-L228). You can override this JS view with the [map section](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/configuration/yaml/jsmodules/#map) in jsmodules.yml configuration file.

Comment: Hello again! I tried setting this up, but it seems that I'm missing something.
Here's what I did : I created my JS file by copying the source of the shipping JS file and removed the part you indicated with the currency. I created the jsmodules.yml file in `Resources/config/oro/jsmodules.yml` inside my bundle, and put the `map.oroshipping.'oroshipping/js/app/views/shipping-rule-method-view'` key with my JS file, and installed the assets. Did I put the wrong key perhaps? (I tried replacing oroshipping with a * wildcard just in case, it didn't work either)

Comment: To apply the above changes, it's required to run `oro:assets:install` command

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn't work. I already installed the assets before, I tried reinstalling them again for good measure. Nothing happens on the admin menu, and I don't seem to see any logs, so I'm not certain what's wrong.
My `jsmodules.yml` file contains the following yml data (inlined as I can't format things here): `map: oroshipping: 'oroshipping/js/app/views/shipping-rule-method-view': 'gdmshipping/js/shipping-rule-method-view'`. I tried appending a ".js" extension to both the key and the data, to no avail.